# Tabs not rendered in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

After updating R and Rstudio for other reasons, {.tabset} is no longer working in rmarkdown.

Here is the html code produced before the update (I've removed > to make the code visible in this html):

div id="combined-plot" class="section level2 tabset"
h2 Combined Plot /h2

And here's the code produced after the update:

p ##Combined Plot {.tabset}

Here's what I've tried so far which hasn't worked:

- Completely uninstalled R studio and all versions of R and reinstalled
- installed pandoc 2.9 because of issues identified with pandoc 2.8 (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1723)
- Uninstalled pandoc 2.9, Rstudio, and R again and reinstalled R studio (with included pandoc 2.7) and R
- Observed rtools not installed warning so I followed instructions of (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3563) and defined the path with the following code:

  ```
  Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/rtools/usr/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))

  Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/rtools/mingw64/bin/")

  Sys.setenv(BINPREF64 = "C:/rtools/mingw64/bin/")
  ```

  `find_rtools(T)` output was TRUE
- I uninstalled R and reinstalled R and ran this path code before installing all my packages.

Nothing has worked so far so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you show US your complete Rmd Code?

Comment: Sure. I've created a simple project to demonstrate tabs and loaded it to git: https://github.com/AleneOnion/dummy.git

My output has this:
<p>##Tabulated Data {.tabset}

When my colleagues run this the tabs are rendered so I don't think it's an issue with the script.

Comment: I think the error is very simple: just add a whitespace between H2 header ## and the text: ## graphed Data {.tabset} instead of ##graphed Data {.tabset}

Comment: It worked!!!! I can't believe it. I was really skeptical when I saw you suggestion because I had been using these scripts for months and they worked fine before I did the reinstalls. That's so strange but i'll take it. You are a lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very simple: just add a whitespace between H2 header ## and the text: ## graphed Data {.tabset} instead of ##graphed Data {.tabset}

WRONG:

```
##Tabulated Data {.tabset}
```

RIGHT:

```
## Tabulated Data {.tabset}
```